# C++ template symbol visibility differences between macOS and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, linker, elf

What are the rules and rule differences between macOS and linux, for the visibility
of internal/external symbols in shared libraries? In particular, the external
visibility of C++ template instantiations. It looks like gcc on linux allows linking to 'unexported' symbols....

Example:

If I have an templated class with a virtual function "interface.h":

```
template <int T>
class SomeTemplate {
public:
  virtual void test_fun(void) const;
};
```

Whose function is defined in a private source file inside a library somelib.so 
"somelib.cpp" (compiled with `g++ -fPIC -shared -o libsomelib.so somelib.cpp`),
where the library also uses the instantiated template in other functions/class methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "interface.h"

template <int T>
void SomeTemplate<T>::test_fun(void) const
{
  std::cout << "Test function " << T << std::endl;
}

void something(void)
{
  SomeTemplate<1>().test_fun();
}

// Explicit template instantiation required for macOS - see below
// template class SomeTemplate<1>;
```

When compiled on linux the template symbols end up in the "W" section, as
determined by `nm -C libsomelib.so | grep SomeTemplate`:

```
0000000000000bc4 W SomeTemplate<1>::SomeTemplate()
0000000000000bc4 W SomeTemplate<1>::SomeTemplate()
0000000000000be0 W SomeTemplate<1>::test_fun() const
0000000000201060 V typeinfo for SomeTemplate<1>
0000000000000c90 V typeinfo name for SomeTemplate<1>
0000000000201040 V vtable for SomeTemplate<1>
```

And using this in a program/library that links to this somelib works fine, e.g. "program.cpp" (`g++ -o testlib libsomelib.so program.cpp`):

```
#include "interface.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  SomeTemplate<1>().test_fun();
  return 0;
}
```

However, compiling on macOS (and manually demangling) puts the symbols required
by the program in what `man nm` calls the "local (non-external) text section":

```
0000000000000f70 t SomeTemplate<1>::SomeTemplate()
0000000000000fe0 t SomeTemplate<1>::SomeTemplate()
0000000000000f90 t SomeTemplate<1>::test_fun() const
00000000000020d8 D typeinfo for SomeTemplate<1>
0000000000001f50 S typeinfo name for SomeTemplate<1>
00000000000020c0 d vtable for SomeTemplate<1>
```

And so it seems that being a private symbol, the linking of the program fails with undefined symbols:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SomeTemplate<1>::test_fun() const"
```

It seems that the usage of the templated class inside the library isn't
enough - I need to explicitly declare the template instantiation e.g. 
the commented line in somelib.cpp, then the symbol ends up in "T", visible, and the test program compiles and runs.

What's causing this difference in behaviour, what terminology do I have to use to understand this, and is there a way to get the platforms to match behaviour? Is the non-explicit instantiation just considered bad practice that was bound to break eventually?

(this is a large project I've joined where the upstream library developers aren't necessarily amenable to changes, and my predecessor evidently gave up and forced everything to static linking when compiling on macOS).

Comment: Speaking from experience, its awful. I recently tried to clear a Microsoft warning about non-standard extension used for `extern template class ...` for a cross-platform library (Android, BSDs, iOS, Linux, Microsoft, OS X, Solaris, Unix). Even though it tested good locally and on Travis and AppVeyor, it broke certain versions of Clang and OS X. Also see [Commit 429047a8e9765896](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/429047a8e9765896178d2254c5469b4a5f036d67), which backed out the change that attempted to squash the Microsoft warning.

Comment: Getting back to your example, in your source file, you need either `template class SomeTemplate<1>` or `extern template class SomeTemplate<1>`. Once you get past the compiler (problem #1), you still have to mount Apple, Microsoft and Solaris linkers (problem #2). They are different than GNU's linker. It will be a `#define` mess like [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L727). You will probably need to introduce a define on some platforms that differentiates between static and shared object builds.